# Как создать класс со статическим свойством, которое будет содержать значение количества созданных экземпляров?

Tags: php, ооп

мне нужно понять как создать класс со статическим свойством, которое будет содержать значение количества созданных экземпляров?Я новичок в ООП. Можете помочь?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class A
{
    public static $f = 0;

    public function __construct()
    {
        self::$f++;
    }

    public function __destruct()
    {
        self::$f--;
    } 
}

$a = new A;
$b = new A;

echo A::$f; // 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Объявляете статическую переменную-счётчик, и увеличиваете её значение при каждом вызове конструктора класса *(или при каждом клонировании объекта)*. А в случае удаления объекта уменьшаете значение счётчика. Ну а что бы вручную нельзя было изменить значение счётчика, ограничиваете к нему доступ с помощью модификатора private, и дописываете публичный статический метод, возвращающий значение счётчика:

```
class ObjectCounting
{
    private static $count = 0;

    public function __construct()
    {
        self::counter();
    }

    public function __clone()
    {
        self::counter();
    }

    public function __destruct()
    {
        self::$count--;
    }

    private static function counter()
    {
        self::$count++;
    }

    public static function all()
    {
        return self::$count;
    }
}

$ob_1 = new ObjectCounting;
$ob_2 = new ObjectCounting;
$ob_3 = clone $ob_2;
var_dump(ObjectCounting::all()); // 3

unset($ob_2);
var_dump(ObjectCounting::all()); // 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class TestExample
{
    public static $instanceCount = 0;

    public function __construct()
    {
        ++static::$instanceCount;
    }
}

$a = new TestExample();
$b = new TestExample();
$c = TestExample::instanceCount;
```